# Filter SPARL queries results based on words in URL

Tags: url, filter, sparql

I am a new comer on sparql 
I need to extract some link from this database 
https://data.gesis.org/claimskg/site/#web

But I just want to extract the original news so I need your help to find how to do a query that filter the result based on URL (like not display the url containing `politifact` or `snopes` which are the fact checking article).

So my main ID is just to filter all the url in the property citation and display the ones which don't contain the domain name of the fact checking website used in the data base.

I don't know if it's clear sorry.

I tried to use  `filter contains(?citation,'politifact', 'snopes')}` but this function take only strings as first argument.

Some code:

```
PREFIX itsrdf: <https://www.w3.org/2005/11/its/rdf#>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?claim ?claimReview ?citation ?text WHERE {
 ?claimReview schema:itemReviewed ?claim.
 ?claim a schema:CreativeWork.
 ?claim schema:text ?text ; schema:citation ?citation.
 filter contains(?citation,'trump')}
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: `filter contains(str(?citation),'trump')}`

Comment: not that I understand why you want to search in the URL for words, but ok. properties `schema:keywords` and `schema:text` seem more natural to me, but it's your query in the end and if it works, why not

Comment: OR something like `PREFIX itsrdf: <https://www.w3.org/2005/11/its/rdf#>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX nif: <http://persistence.uni-leipzig.org/nlp2rdf/ontologies/nif-core#>
SELECT ?claim ?claimReview ?citation ?text WHERE {
 ?claimReview schema:itemReviewed ?claim.
 ?claim a schema:CreativeWork.
 ?claim schema:text ?text ; schema:citation ?citation.
 ?claim schema:mentions/nif:isString ?s 
 filter contains(str(?s),'Trump')

} LIMIT 100`

Comment: Thank you it works !! Well I I just need to extract some data once and quickly so I didn’t looked deep in sparql :)